# Css Grid media query element pushed outside

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to learn CSS grid but some strange issue keeps acquiring. So I am building a simple grid with 5 areas Header, Main Footer left sidebar, and right sidebar. It works fine and here is the code but when resizing for some strange reason right sidebar appears beneath the grid on the right here is also my codepen https://codepen.io/yuri-gaiduk/pen/xxOOOda. Just to clarify after the media query is applied I only want to see Header, Midlle, and Footer

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="red_box left-bar box"><h2>On left</h2></div>
   <div class="green_box header box">Heade</div>
   <div class="orange_box rigth-bar box"><h2>On right</h2></div>
   <div class="coral_box main box">Main</div>
   <div class="blue_box bottom box"><h2>Footer</h2></div> 
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
.container{
           display:grid;
           grid-template-columns:auto;
           grid-template-rows:auto;
           grid-template-areas: 
                              "leftbar header header header rightbar"
                              "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar"
                              "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar"
                              "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar"
                              "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar"
                              "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar"
                              "footer footer footer footer footer";
           height:400px;
       }


      .box{
          border:1px solid black;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          text-align:center;
      }


     .rigth-bar{
          grid-area:rightbar;
     }

     .left-bar{
          grid-area:leftbar;
     }

    .header{
          grid-area:header;
    }

    .main{
          grid-area:midle;
    }

    .bottom{
          grid-area:footer;
    }

    .red_box{
          background-color:red;
    }

    .orange_box{
          background-color:orange;
    }


   .blue_box{
         background-color:blue;
    }

   .green_box{
         background-color:green;
   }

   .coral_box{
         border:1px solid black;
         background-color:coral;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         text-align:center;
   }

  @media (max-width:1000px){
      .container{
          grid-template-areas:
                             "header header header"
                             "midle midle midle"
                             "midle midle midle"
                             "midle midle midle"
                             "midle midle midle"
                             "midle midle midle"
                             "footer footer footer";
       }

  }
```

Comment: What's the intended behaviour when the media query is active?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified it. What I want is for the grid to show the only Header, Middle, and Footer no sidebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving `leftbar` and `rightbar` out of your `grid-template-areas` **won't remove** those elements from the DOM, it will just take them out of the grid. Your left-bar is actually directly *behind* your right-bar when your media query is active (which is why you can't see it).

You'll also want to set `display: none` on them:

```
.left-bar, .rigth-bar{
  display: none;
}
```

Here's an example snippet from your code pen:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "leftbar header header header rightbar" "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar" "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar" "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar" "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar" "leftbar midle midle midle rightbar" "footer footer footer footer footer";
  height: 400px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.rigth-bar {
  grid-area: rightbar;
}

.left-bar {
  grid-area: leftbar;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.main {
  grid-area: midle;
}

.bottom {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.red_box {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange_box {
  background-color: orange;
}

.blue_box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green_box {
  background-color: green;
}

.coral_box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "midle midle midle" "midle midle midle" "midle midle midle" "midle midle midle" "midle midle midle" "footer footer footer";
  }
  .left-bar,
  .rigth-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red_box left-bar box">
    <h2>On left</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="green_box header box">Heade</div>
  <div class="orange_box rigth-bar box">
    <h2>On right</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="coral_box main box">Main</div>
  <div class="blue_box bottom box">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```